# Parse.com local datastore: Tried to save an object with a new, unsaved child

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, local-datastore

I am testing Parse local datastore to evaluate if I can use it as a replacement for SQLite for an app that would mostly be used offline. I may have found a bug?

Consider the Product and Order classes:

```
class Product : PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    @NSManaged var productName: String!
}

class Order : PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    @NSManaged var orderId: String!
    @NSManaged var product: Product!
}
```

With internet disabled, when I run the following code, it crashes on the last line with `Tried to save an object with a new, unsaved child.`

```
let p = Product()
p.productName = "Test Product"
p.saveEventually()

let o = Order()
o.orderId = "TestOrder01"
o.product = p
o.saveEventually()

let query = Order.query()
query.whereKey("product", equalTo: p)

let results = query.findObjects() // crashes with Tried to save an object with a new, unsaved child.
```

is it a platform limitation or a bug in my code?

**NOTE** I have typed the code from memory, so ignore minor issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by your use of `saveEventually` causing a racing condition, like so:

1. You create a Product.
2. You tell Parse to save it when it has time - but it doesn't right away.
3. You create an Order.
4. When you tell Parse to save the order eventually, it checks to make sure the parent is already saved, which it isn't - hence the error.

You need to ensure the parent is saved before creating a child.

Instead, do a saveInBackGroundWithBlock on the Product, then do the creation and save of the Order in the completion block.

Comment: You are right, but my point is shouldn't `saveEventually()` save to the local datastore (since the user has no internet)? It's a very common scenario for a user to create objects and the code to query them to update the UI (while being offline). So, this really is a platform limitation, One can't run queries unless the data is already saved *online*, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The method you may need **pinObjectInBackground**.  This is actually how you *save locally*

The **saveEventually** method is used when you want to sync local data with the cloud. **saveEventually** pins but will save to the cloud the first chance it gets.

When you just **pinObjectInBackground** it saves it locally but will not attempt to save anything offline.

Answer (score 0):

See the code below. Beware I changed it without XCODE, so it may have typos :) The code below will only look to satisfy your query from the local datastore. The "saveEventually" will push (sync) with Parse cloud, but if you are looking for data to be be locally available, it must be pinned, with or without a name.

```
let p = Product()
p.productName = "Test Product"
p.pinWithName("test")
p.saveEventually()

let o = Order()
o.orderId = "TestOrder01"
o.product = p

o.pinWithName("test")
o.saveEventually()

let query = Order.query()
query.fromPinWithName("test")
query.whereKey("product", equalTo: p)

let results = query.findObjects()
```